# how to send a pdf base64 variable through a nodejs request?

Tags: node.js, pdf, requestjs

Trying to send a base64 pdf string with request, but I can't seem to figure out the proper structure of the request.  Thanks in advance for the help!

```
    var dpdf = pdfvar.toString('base64');

    var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: dpdf,
    url: FILEPICKER_URL,
    headers: [
      {
        name: 'content-type',
        value: 'application/pdf'
      }
    ]
  };

  request(options, function(err, httpResponse, body){ 
    console.log('body: ', body);
    console.log('code ', httpResponse.statusCode)
  });
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, the resulting pdf file sent to filepicker is a corrupted file.  But I know dpdf is fine bc I emailed it as an attachment through mandrill and it worked fine.

Comment: The problem is something with the options object but I'm not sure what.  Whether I need to include it as a json object or include another header field...not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The other side is expecting a PDF

```
application/pdf
```

and not a BASE64 representation of it.

Anyway, looking at what you are trying to do, without necessarily understanding how you are trying to do it... I would try and append a data url compatible header to your string like so :

```
var dpdf = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfvar.toString('base64')
```

Comment: to provide greater context, I am trying to replace a file uploaded via filepicker.io.  I am doing that via post request but need to figure out how to send the pdf